# Discretizing and solve $u''=\lambda u $ with Matrix scheme

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, discrete-calculus

as a part of a computer project, I need to solve

$u''=\lambda u\Longleftrightarrow (T-\lambda) u, $

with $T$ the discretized central difference second derivative (stencil/kernel: 1,-2,1).

Details are also covered in [Solve the eigenvalue problem $y''=\lambda y$ numerically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542976).

To solve this numerically, we first use the SciPy eigenvalue functions to obtain the eigenvalues and then use the first eigenvalue to solve the linear system of equations with a kernel of (1,-2-$\lambda$,1). Therefore, this equation is equal to $Au=0$.

My problem is that this matrix $A$ has a determinate $\neq 0 $, therefore it is trivially solved by $u=\vec{0}$. How can I obtain the eigenfunctions numerically if the solutions fall back to the trivial solution.

Note: There are also boundary conditions which also do not produce a determinate $\neq 0$ and/or change b from being $\vec{0}$.

I am thankful for every bit of enlightenment and I would also appreciate feedback about my posting style as I am a first time poster.

Best
jw

Comment: Well, the whole idea is to find $\lambda$ such that $\det(A)=0$...

Comment: Yes, but the eigenvalues of $A$ given by scipy don't do that 

thanks for the fast reply

Comment: the eigenvalues of $A$ are not what you need here. $A=T-\lambda I$, so you have to choose $\lambda$ equal to an eigenvalue of $T$...

Comment: Thank you, that cleared up the mathematical part of my problem!
Now I am back to questioning my code.
Best jw